# Cech Cohomology and module structure

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

I just came across a question I had never thought about and that could be simple, but I can't answer it. If we consider a scheme $X$ and we pick a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-modules $\mathcal{F}$, under some assumptions we can compute its cohomology either via an injective resolution or with Cech cohomology. Both the answers carry an $\mathcal{O}_X$-module structure, but the theorem that states that the answers we get with the two approaches is the same is always stated saying that the *abelian groups* are the same. Therefore my question, is the isomorphism between Cech cohomology and cohomology as a derived functor an isomorphism of $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer:**

I'm going to explain in what sense the answer is yes, and why the "counterexample" I gave in my last answer was contrived.

First, recall that the cohomology $H^i(X, F) = R^i\Gamma(X, F)$ is only defined up to natural isomorphism, and depends on the choice of injective resolution of $F$. So, let's denote by $H^i(F,I)$ the cohomology with respect to an injective resolution $I$ of $F$.

If we pick a different resolution $J$ there is a natural map $H^i(F,I) \cong H^i(F,J)$ which doesn't depend on all the choices you make to construct it. So, if $I$ happens to be a resolution by $\mathcal O$-modules, this makes $H^i(F,I)$ an $\mathcal O$-module, and even if $J$ is not a resolution by $\mathcal O$-modules the natural isomorphism gives its cohomology an $\mathcal O$-module structure.

Since the map from the Cech sheaf to an injective resolution also gives natural maps $\check H^i(X,F) \to H^i(F,I)$ and $\check H^i(X,F) \to H^i(F,J)$, these will respect both the $\mathcal O$-action on $I$ and on $J$.

So in this sense the answer is *yes*, the map is always an isomorphism of $\mathcal O$-modules.

The example I gave originally is actually pretty contrived. It arose from this observation: If you take a complex of $\mathcal O$-modules $J$ which is an injective resolution of $F$ as abelian groups, but for which the augmentation $\varepsilon : F \to J$ is *not* $\mathcal O$-linear, then the map $\check H^i(X,F) \to H^i(F,J)$ will not be $\mathcal O$-linear, nor will the natural isomorphism $H^i(F,I) \cong H^i(F,J)$ with respect to be $\mathcal O$-actions.

---

**Original answer:**

How do we prove that sheaf cohomology and cech cohomology are the same anyway? For reference see a nice note on this here: pub.math.leidenuniv.nl/~edixhovensj/teaching/2011-2012/AAG/lecture_14.pdf or see Hartshorne.

Basically you can build a resolution of $\mathcal F$ by making a sheaf-version of the Cech complex (whose global sections is the usual Cech complex and which is a sheaf of $\mathcal O_X$-modules). After you check this is a resolution, it is a fact that any resolution will map to an injective resolution. This involves making choices, but since the choices are unique up to homotopy you get the well-defined map from Cech cohomology to sheaf cohomology. But what if you switch the category from $\mathcal O_X$-modules to sheaves of abelian groups - are the choices still unique up to homotopies taken from the other category?

The answer is no. Consider the case $X$ is a point. Let $\mathcal F = \mathcal O_X =  \underline{k}$ be the constant sheaf. If we compute in the category of sheaves of abelian groups then we have the freedom to replace $\mathcal F$ with an injective resolution. One injective resolution is $\phi: \underline{k} \to \underline{k}$ taken to be any isomorphism chosen specifically not to be $k$-linear but only additive. Then in this case the map between sheaf cohomology and cech cohomology is not $\mathcal O$-linear by design because it coincides with $\phi$ itself.

So, if you  want an $\mathcal O$ linear map you can get one for free, and I think it is pretty standard to assume this map is $\Gamma(\mathcal O,X)$-linear.

Comment: So you're saying that the isomorphism is for sure an isomorphism of $\mathcal{O}$ modules only if I pick an injective resolution of $\mathcal{O}$ modules and make the Cech complex map into this resolution. If I pass to the category of sheaves of abelian groups and then pick a resolution by flasque sheaves the resulting isomorphism might not be an isomorphism of $\mathcal{O}$-modules, even if the target (cohomology as a derived functor) is an $\mathcal{O}$-module. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Actually If the cohomology is an $\mathcal O$ module I think this means you must have taken a resolution in the category of $\mathcal O$ modules. In which case you may choose a map from the cech sheaf to it which is $\mathcal O$ linear.

Comment: In other words, if you acquire an $\mathcal O$ module structure on the sheaf cohomology by some other means than inheriting it from the injective resolution, then there is no guarantee the map will be $\mathcal O$ linear.

Comment: I think in practice this won’t happen though, the module structure will always come from a resolution and the map on cohomology will be $\mathcal O$ linear.

Comment: Thank you for your new answer!